# Sql Dump growing so fast

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

permission to ask. I have a SQL dump with very fast file growth. what should I do to stop it?
The solution I have done so far is to delete the file.[image]

Comment: Frequent dumps are an indicator of data corruption or bug. Make sure `DBCC CHECKDB` is clean and you are on at least the latest service pack. Note [SQL Server 2008 has reached end-of-life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008) and is no longer supported. Add the dump summary to your question or DBCC error output.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation @Dan Guzman.

for your information, I have 600 databases. does this DBCC CHECKDB run to all databases?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a SQL dump with very fast file growth. what should I do to stop it?

Dan is correct, when this happens it's almost exclusively some type of corruption or a potential product defect. Much as Dan also points out, form your screenshot it looks as though you're using SQL Server 2008R2 which is entirely out of support.

You have a few options:

- Look at the errorlog and get an idea of the reason for the dumps
- Look at the dump logs to get an idea of the reason for the dumps
- Open up the dumps to find out why the dumps are ocurring
- Blindly run checkdb on all databases

It's impossible to give more help than that given the current set of information in the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation @Sean Gallardy

Comment: Most important of all make sure your SQL Server 2008/ 2008 r2 is updated with latest SP and CU. Although its end of life but this may fix already existing bug.

Comment: I found an error like this after running checkdb.  

CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 11 consistency errors in the database 'AstraHangfire'.
repair_rebuild is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (AstraHangfire).
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC prints error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: @jubeysimanjuntak looks like there are some consistency issues, we don't know what they are, please add them to your original post.

Comment: @jubeysimanjuntak Then you should run `REPAIR_REBUILD` it's pretty much lossless, but it often doesn't work. Alternatively restore from backup if at all possible. Do not run `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` unless you are prepared to lose some or all of your data

Comment: thanks for the answers. I don't have a file backup on the database. I mean, the file backup before this problem. this problem happened 1 month ago. solution for now that I do is to delete this file daily.